# Applying flyweight pattern for controls?

Tags: optimization, controls, design-patterns

My application contains a grid that can have up to 100 cells. I want to add a custom control in each cell. All instances of the custom control take data from a shared repository. The controls look identical except user can interact with the control in each cell independently.

The problem I am facing now is that the creating of each control can take up to 50 ms, that means for 10x10 grid, it will take 5 seconds to populate the grid.

I am thinking of using flyweight. I am not familiar with this pattern. The only thing I know is that it allows a single object to be shared amongst many "clients".  But not sure how it can be done because each control can only be assigned to one cell (parent). I can't share the control, can I?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a bit like I tried to make my first Excel-like application under OS/2's Presentation Manager.  That was in 1990 if I remember correctly (yes, I'm that old).  It proved to be impossible to create as many edit controls as I had cells in my sheet.

Instead of creating all the controls from the start, make a 'preview' of the control.  In most cases it's sufficient to just show the text, just like Excel.

Only create the control if it is really needed, e.g. the user clicks on a cell.  Keep this control alive until the user clicks on another cell, presses enter, ...